# Authentication for multiple databases in couchbase sync gateway

Tags: authentication, synchronization, couchbase, pouchdb, gateway

How can I authenticate for more than one database simultaneously using Couchbase sync gateway?

I'm developing a mobile app where I use pouchdb that synchronizes via couchbase sync gateway with a couchbase server. I have to databases that should be synchronized: "messages" and "profiles".

The Sync works really well, but I have one problem: I only can authenticate for ONE database at the same time, but not for both simultaneously: I'm using custom authentication as described [here](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/guides/sync-gateway/administering-sync-gateway/authenticating-users/index.html%20here) which is achieved by calling the "/database1/_session" endpoint. This then returns a cookie that logs me in for database 1. If I now want to synchronize the second database too, I make a call to "/database2/_session" which overrides the first cookie, i.e. I'm now able to synchronize the second database, but not the first anymore.

Is there a way to enable authentication for more than one database? Is there a way to create global users, i.e. users that are not valid just for one database? Or is there another way to solve this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, after hours of trying to write proxies that manipulate the cookies etc. I found a much easier solution:

In my server app, I can set a token as password for the user for all databases, which I can send to the app on login. The app can then just use http basic authentication:

```
  this.db.sync(this.cfg.couchbase + 'messages', {
    live: true,
    retry: true,
    ajax: {
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.userID + ':' + token)
      }
    }
  }).on('change', this.changed.bind(this))
    .on('error', err => console.error(err));
});
```